# Fill struct dynamically from parameters

Tags: json, go, dynamic, unmarshalling

I've the following struct which works as expected Im getting 
data and I was  able

```
type Service struct {
    Resources    []struct {
        Model struct {
            Name                string `json:"name"`
            Credentials         struct {
                path string `json:"path"`
                Vts struct {
                    user string `json:"user"`
                    id    string `json:"id"`
                    address      string `json:"address"`
                } `json:"vts"`
            } `json:"credentials"`
        } `json:"model"`
    } `json:"resources"`
}

service:= Service{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &service
```

The data is like following,

service1

```
{
    "resources": [
        "model": {
          "name": "cred",
          "credentials": {
            "path": "path in fs",
            "vts": {
              "user": "stephane", 
              "id": "123",
              "address": "some address"
            }
          },
        }
      },
```

Now some services providing additional data under vts for example now we have 3 fields (user/id/address) but some services (service1) can provides additional data like email, secondName ,etc . but the big problem here is that 
I need to get it from parameters since (service 2) education, salary etc

Service2

```
{
    "resources": [
        "model": {
          "name": "cred",
          "credentials": {
            "path": "path in fs",
            "vts": {
              "user": "stephane",
              "id": "123",
              "address": "some address",
              "email" : "some email",
              "secondName" : "secondName"
            }
          },
        }
      },
```

service N

```
{
    "resources": [
        "model": {
          "name": "cred",
          "credentials": {
            "path": "path in fs",
            "vts": {
              "user": "stephane",
              "id": "123",
              "address": "some address",
              "salary" : "1000000"
            }
          },
        }
      },
```

Of course If I know **in advance** the fields I can put them all in the struct and use `omitempty` **but I dont know, I just get it as parameter to the function** (the new properties names) , some service can provide 10 more fields in this struct (which I should get the properties name of them as `args[]`to the functions) but I don't know them in advance, this should be dynamic somehow ....is there a nice way to handle it in Golang ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know the fields in advance, then don't use a struct but something that is also "dynamic": a map.

```
type Service struct {
    Resources []struct {
        Model struct {
            Name        string `json:"name"`
            Credentials struct {
                Path string                 `json:"path"`
                Vts  map[string]interface{} `json:"vts"`
            } `json:"credentials"`
        } `json:"model"`
    } `json:"resources"`
}
```

`map[sting]interface{}` can hold values of any type. If you know all fields will hold a `string` value, you may also use a `map[string]string` so it will be easier to work with it.

Example with input JSON:

```
{
    "resources": [
      {
        "model": {
          "name": "cred",
          "credentials": {
            "path": "path in fs",
            "vts": {
              "user": "stephane", 
              "id": "123",
              "address": "some address",
              "dyn1": "d1value",
              "dyn2": "d2value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Testing it:

```
service := Service{}
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &service)
fmt.Printf("%q %v", service, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dW-bBZR6NGN)):

```
{[{{"cred" {"path in fs" map["dyn2":"d2value" "user":"stephane" "id":"123" 
    "address":"some address" "dyn1":"d1value"]}}}]} <nil>
```

Now if you want to collect values from the `Vts` map for a set of keys, this is how you can do it:

```
args := []string{"dyn1", "dyn2"}
values := make([]interface{}, len(args))
for i, arg := range args {
    values[i] = service.Resources[0].Model.Credentials.Vts[arg]
}
fmt.Println(values)
```

Output of the above will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/isl2gWk79Xa)):

```
[d1value d2value]
```

Comment: Thanks 1+ , is there a way to provide for example "dyn1" & "dyn2" as `parameter` to the function like `args` and return only them ?

Comment: Just iterate over fields you're interested in, and collect them from the map. That's easy.

Comment: Can you please provide example how would you do this ? becouse when I use struct I get it for free...